# Paste a copied data range in all open workbooks using a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to set up a VBA macro to loop through all open files and  paste the same range of cells on each workbook in the loop.  I was able to do essentially the reverse of this process with the simple macro below (LoopEachOpenWorkbook) I would copy a range from each open workbook and paste it into a central workbook so I could aggregate all the data.

```
 Sub LoopEachOpenWorkbook()

Dim wb As Workbook

 For Each wb In Workbooks

      If wb.Name <> "FILE NAME.xlsm" Then

              wb.Activate

              ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal

              Sheets("Sheet1").Select

              Range("A2:S20").Select

              Selection.Copy

              Windows("FILE NAME.xlsm").Activate

              Range("A1").Select

              Selection.End(xlDown).Select

              ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

             ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

    End If
    Next wb
    End Sub
```

I figured I would be able to use a similar method to update each workbook with a new data set.  I attempted this with macro listed below (Update Matrix).  What my hope was that I could just copy the data I wanted so that it was on the clipboard and the macro would simply paste what was already in the clipboard.  I also tried this with including the copy within the macro but prior to the loop.  No matter what I try I am still getting an error on the line of code to paste.  I have tried various ways  to paste and I am still getting the error.

```
Sub Update Matrix()

Dim wb As Workbook





For Each wb In Workbooks

  If wb.Name <> "FILE NAME.xlsm" Then



          wb.Activate

          ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlNormal

          Sheets("Sheet 1").Select

          ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"

          Range("A5").Select

          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _

        :=False, Transpose:=False

          ActiveSheet.Protect "password", True, True

          Sheets("Sheet 2").Select



  End If

Next wb
```

Does the copy need to be included in the macro and furthermore within the loop?  Would I have to go back to my source workbook and re-copy the range for each time I paste into the new workbook in the loop?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to copy and paste, you can transfer the value directly, but you need to specify the origin (unless your code accesses the clipboard).

```
Sub UpdateMatrix()

Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> "FILE NAME.xlsm" Then
        With wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
            .Unprotect "password"
            'in the line below you need to specify the source cell (and sheet)
            .Range("A5").Value = Workbooks("FILE NAME.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
            .Protect "password", True, True
        End With
    End If
Next wb

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfect thanks.  Still curious why the paste would not work but now knowing this I can't imagine a situation where this wouldn't just replace a paste.

Comment: My pleasure. You weren't copying anything in your code. I think VBA clears the clipboard.